# Entity Framework Repository Pattern with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, repository-pattern, observablecollection

I have watched Mosh Hamedani's course on EF as well as read articles on MSDN. I have also read a few discussions here in StackOverflow over this. But I cannot still understand it properly.

I am trying to use Entity Framework with repository pattern in WPF. Now, everywhere I see people using repository pattern in such a way that it returns a IEnumerable<> of items. However, since I am trying to bind these to datagrids which needs to be updated, is it not better to return ObservableCollection?

Also, I watched a few tutorials where they blindly remove and replace ICollection and Hashset in the entities created by EF with ObservableCollection. However, [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574514(v=vs.113).aspx) is a tutorial where it says, and I quote, "Find and replace the first occurrence of “HashSet” with “ObservableCollection”. This occurrence is located approximately at line 50. Do not replace the second occurrence of HashSet found later in the code." It does not even explain why I shouldn't replace the second occurrence at all.

Can anyone tell me how to understand which ICollection and Hashset are safe to be replaced with ObservableCollection?

As a side note, I have introduced INotifyPropertyChanged in Entities. Is it better practice to use ObservableObject?

Any help would be genuinely welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practices suggest to segregate all the responsibilities, ideally once per class. There is no reason that a contract of a repository pattern returns a collection of type `ObservableCollection<>`. This is not *needed* and add unnecessary overheads.

To properly bind an UI element to your repository pattern and updates the data source accordingly, we are introducing another responsibility: the coordination of the update of the data. You can typically implement this responsibility using the MVVM pattern, where your view model expose your initial `IEnumerable<>` collection to an `ObservableCollection<>` to your view and call your repository when updates are triggered.

Thus, the workflow to load data becomes:

> Repository(`IEnumerable<>`) --[LOAD]--> ViewModel(`ObservableCollection<>`) --> View

and the workflow to update data becomes:

> View --[UPDATE]--> ViewModel --[PROPAGATE]--> Repository

The view model takes care of the `ObservableCollection<>` which is a need of the UI layer and calls the right method(s) of your repository (for example `repo.Save(myItem)`) to keep the data source updated.

You got confused because you wish to use in one hand the repository pattern, that should introduce a notion of abstraction (the implementation can be replaced by anything) and the Microsoft guide, that suggests to implement a strong coupling between your data and UI layers.

The bottom line here is either you go with what Microsoft suggest with a strong coupling, or with a loosely coupled solution using a repository pattern. Nonetheless, if you try to do the both at the same time, you are going to end up with a leaky abstraction and only get the drawbacks of the two solutions.

---

EDIT to suggest a contract for the repository.

```
public interface ItemsRepository
{
   IEnumerable<Item> GetAll();
   void Update(Item item);
}
```

Then, the UI layer will only reference this interface to interact with your database. You can now implement it with any ORM library or why not a web service if you suddently need to.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I am actually using MVVM pattern, but my concern is somewhere else. Let's say, I have a datagrid which I want to bind to an `ObservableCollection` called `TestCollection`. Now, let's say I am populating this collection like this:

`ObservableCollection<items> TestCollection = new ObservableCollection<items>(UnitOfWork.Items.GetAll());`

Now, if I add any item to `TestCollection` and then call `UnitofWork.Complete()`, common sense dictates that the item would not be added to the database. How am I supposed to alleviate this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was too chatty in my answer. You are right, the common sense indicates that the database won't be updated and hopefully, because you didn't indicate what changed to your repository. The idea with MVVM is that your view model listens the event on your `ObservableCollection<>` (modified using your datagrid). Once a change triggers your event, you can for example calls a dedicated method in your repository to update your record, such as `UnitOfWork.Update(myItem)`. Does that make sense in your case ?

Comment: Thank you, this is much better. Conceptually, this is supposed to work. I will try it tomorrow and, if I face any more hurdles, I'll let you know. Thank you once again.

Comment: No worries, it's always a brain-teaser once you leave the perfect world of the Microsoft's guides to dig a real-world solution. :) This solution guarantees that the your UI and data layer are properly loosely coupled, so you can replace one without any impact of the other one. Feel free to flag this answer as the solution of your question on StackOverflow if it solves your needs. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have hit a new hurdle. There is no `UnitOfWork.Update(myItem)` method, because EF6 has a change tracker that renders it redundant. However, what I can do is this
`var a = UnitOfWork.Items.GetAll();
ObservableCollection<items> TestCollection = new ObservableCollection<items>(a)`

And when the collection changes, `a = TestCollection.ToList()`

And when I need to save the changes, `UnitOfWork.Complete()`.

It feels extremely kludgy, because it is. It's ugly, and I will get rid of it as soon as I come up with an alternative. But it gets the job done **for now**.

Comment: You have that bad feeling because you implemented it in a leaky way. You have to consider that the code behind your repository is a black box, like if you not longer use Entity Framework. Thus, you are going to implement it properly. Of course Entity Framework allows you to make it faster, but that's the price to pay to have a solid abstracted implementation. :) You need to extend your repository contract to add an equivalent to the `Update` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will indeed extend my generic repository to include an `update` method.

Comment: I enhanced my answer to include a typical repository contract to implement for your need (read all the items and update one), to give you a good start.

Comment: I already have an interface like this:
`interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        TEntity GetByPrimaryKey(object primarykey);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void Add(IEnumerable<TEntity> entitylist);

        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(IEnumerable<TEntity> entitylist);

        IEnumerable<TEntity> FindWhere(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    }`
I'll add update to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to decouple your UI from your data layer.
The repository is responsible for managing you data access code (read/write to the db)

Now,how you display and edit your data on the UI is not the repository's problem.
You need a business/presentation layer.

For example,if you have a CustomerRepository like

```
class CustomerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
         return yourContext.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can create a service like

```
class CustomerService
{
    public ObservableCollectionOf<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
         var customers=new CustomerRepository().GetCustomers().OrderBy...;
         return new ObservableCollectionOf(customers);
    }
}
```

You don't have to ,and probably shouldn't ,use UI(InotifyPropertyChanged,Observables) related code on you Entities.

Create ViewModels (in your Business/Presentation Layer) which are responsible for that

Comment: Unfortunately, I have very little experience regarding services. So, I might not be able to use them after all. It'd be swell if you could kindly point me towards some resources from which I can learn it quickly.

Comment: @NibaronChakraborty It's not anything special.it's just a wrapper class around your repository.In my example the repo is just responsible for loading the data from the db.The service is responsible for business logic (ordering/filtering)Also,it doesn't have to return Customer ,it can return a another Model,whatever you need